# How to create a 1:n join and concatenate text attributes?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, attribute-joins

I have 2 polygon layers A and B. 
I would like to join the attributes from B into A for all the polygons from B that intersect A and for text attributes, i would like them concatenate.
But apparently "Join attributes by location" only works for numerical attributes.

Comment: HI, Welcome to GIS.Stackexchange!